# How to resize all content of UIWebView according to width?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I am making an app in which I am getting some html data from web-service and I am showing that data in UIWebView. I have fixed the width of UIWebView "310" but some time data is not come in this frame and data is cut out from edges. I am receiving this data from web -

NSString *resul=@"`<div align=\"left\">As stated Please give a&nbsp;chance&nbsp;to serve you.<br></div><div align=\"left\"><br></div><div align=\"left\"><div class=\"lc\" style=\"margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; clear: left; float: left;`**width: 348px;**`text-align: center;\"><p style=\"text-align: justify; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px;\"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div><div class=\"rc\" style=\"margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; clear: right; float: right;` **width: 348px;** `text-align: center;\"><h2 class=\"why\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; height: 26px; text-align: left; background-image: url(http://www.lipsum.com/images/en/heading.gif); background-position: 0px -52px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;\"></h2><p style=\"text-align: justify; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px;\">It is a long ehat a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p></div></div>`"

I know the reason for that I am receiving the size 348 from web. So I want to ask that how to resize it according to our frame size. I have used -

```
webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webview.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
```

but data is showing in so small size.![data is showing in show small][1]

and I have also used delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad but not get proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the "resul" String.... I mean just change the  "width: 348px;" to "width: 310px;"

Try this:

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"width: 348px;"];
NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"width: 310px;"];
NSRange indexrange = [resul rangeOfString:str1];
while (indexrange.length !=0) {
    [resul replaceCharactersInRange:indexrange withString:str2];
    indexrange = [resul rangeOfString:str1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is not the permanent solution. Form web end it may different some time like width:320 px or width:400px.

Comment: sorry for late answer..... I have just found a way make the width according to the frame.....
Just change str2 from "width: 348px" to "width: 100%"... it will fill up the whole frame.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This was my solution (it also covers orientation change):

```
   float portraitRatio;
```

in - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView add:

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = theWebView.scrollView;
 scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
 portraitRatio = theWebView.bounds.size.width/scroll.contentSize.width;
 [self resizeOnOrientationChanged];


- (void) resizeOnOrientationChanged
{
float zoom;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //iPhone
    for (UIWebView *aWebView in openWebViewsArray) {

        [aWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-30)];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
            zoom = aWebView.bounds.size.width/[webView scrollView].contentSize.width;
        }
        else {
            zoom = portraitRatio;
        }
        NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",zoom];
        [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
    }
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-30)];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        zoom = self.webView.bounds.size.width/[self.webView scrollView].contentSize.width;
    }
    else {
        zoom = portraitRatio;
    }
    NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",zoom];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
}
else {
    for (UIWebView *aWebView in openWebViewsArray) {

        [aWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-60)];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
            zoom = aWebView.bounds.size.width/[webView scrollView].contentSize.width;
        }
        else {
            zoom = portraitRatio;
        }
        NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",zoom];
        [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
    }
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-60)];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        zoom = self.webView.bounds.size.width/[self.webView scrollView].contentSize.width;
    }
    else {
        zoom = portraitRatio;
    }
    NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",zoom];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
}
```

}